# Query XML field in SQL server table

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to query data from a XML field, something new to me.  Despite much searching, I am unable to find an good example that works with my data.  So ...

The table has the fields ReceiptId (PKey) and XMLData
The XMLData field looks like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<receipt number="1" datetime="Wed May 15 08:08:39 PDT 2019" total="75.00">
<items>
<item productid="MULTI" quantity="1" amount="184.00" />
<fees>
<f feeid="Fee1" calculated="5.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee2" calculated="10.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee3" calculated="15.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee4" calculated="20.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee5" calculated="25.00" reason="" />
</fees>
</items>
</receipt>
```

Now for the question ...
What would my SQL Select be to get the calculated amount for Fee3 (e.g. 15.00)?  There are times were Fee3 is not in XMLData so I will need some sort of Exists() statement.

Thanks for helping out a complete newb.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your value is stored as an `xml`, then you can do:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<receipt number="1" datetime="Wed May 15 08:08:39 PDT 2019" total="75.00">
<items>
<item productid="MULTI" quantity="1" amount="184.00" />
<fees>
<f feeid="Fee1" calculated="5.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee2" calculated="10.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee3" calculated="15.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee4" calculated="20.00" reason="" />
<f feeid="Fee5" calculated="25.00" reason="" />
</fees>
</items>
</receipt>';

SELECT f.value('@calculated','varchar(5)') AS calculated
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('receipt/items/fees/f') X(f)
WHERE f.value('@feeid','varchar(5)') = 'Fee3';
```

You use `nodes` to separate the data out into 1 row per `f` element, and then `value` to get the `value`.